# DataTables responsive options are not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

The responsive options for the dataTables plugin are not working. I call them like this:

```
var rectangleTable = $('#rectangle-table').dataTable({
    data: defaultData,
    scrollX:true,
    scrollY:true,
    responsive:{
        details:{
           display: $.fn.dataTable.Responsive.display.childRow,
           type:'column'
        }
    },
    columns:columns,
    "bDestroy": true
});
```

It looks like the responsive script is not working correctly despite being loaded onto the page. I created a sample where I found that the `display:none` would be set as an inline style for the `td` tags in `tbody` which are meant to be hidden. However, when I load it in my application, I find that the `$.fn.DataTable.Responsive` is loaded but none of the inline changes are applied.

I am loading the scripts in the following order:

```
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.0.0/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.0.0/js/responsive.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

These are the css files that I am using:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fontAwesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/bs-3.3.5/jq-2.1.4,dt-1.10.8/datatables.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.0.0/css/responsive.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

[image: Responsive options are not working]

Comment: try with just responsive: true,

Comment: @stibay, I have tried with just `responsive:true` but am still getting the same results,  I have setup a sample page with the data, it looks like the responsive script is not firing(despite being loaded onto the page.)

Comment: hmm try changing .dataTable to .DataTable